# Trailblazer Rails form error "unknown keywords: doc, options, represented, decorator, binding, as, index, model, collection"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform, trailblazer

I'm using the `trailblazer` gem with Rails, and trying to get it to work with a form with nested models. So far, I'm only trying to adapt the `create` and `update` actions to use Operations. **Updating pre-existing nested models works fine. Creating new ones doesn't.**

First, on adding new nested models via a form, I was getting the `Your :populator did not return a Reform::Form instance` error, which went away when I added a populator. Now I'm getting `unknown keywords: doc, options, represented, decorator, binding, as, index, model, collection` out of `Uber::Options::Value#method! uber (0.0.15) lib/uber/options.rb, line 89`. I have no idea how to interpret this.

Comment: Some form/contract code would help!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code. Also the best place to ask TRB questions is in the chatroom : https://gitter.im/trailblazer/chat